# BASH: append to array

Tags: bash

Please be aware that this is just a pseudo code to illustrate the problem:

Directory structure:

```
# tree
.
├── dir1
│   ├── d1_file1
│   ├── d1_file2
│   └── d1_file3
└── dir2
    ├── d2_file1
    ├── d2_file2
    └── d2_file3

2 directories, 6 files
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

list=(
dir1
dir2
)

for dir in ${list[@]}; do
    ls -1 ./tmp/${dir} | while read -a file; do
    files+=(${file})
    echo "${dir} has ${#files[@]} files(s)"
    echo "${dir} files: ${files[@]}"
    done
done
```

Current output:

```
# bash tmp.sh 
dir1 has 1 files(s)
dir1 files: d1_file1
dir1 has 2 files(s)
dir1 files: d1_file1 d1_file2
dir1 has 3 files(s)
dir1 files: d1_file1 d1_file2 d1_file3
dir2 has 1 files(s)
dir2 files: d2_file1
dir2 has 2 files(s)
dir2 files: d2_file1 d2_file2
dir2 has 3 files(s)
dir2 files: d2_file1 d2_file2 d2_file3
```

Desired outcome:

```
# bash tmp.sh
dir1 has 3 files(s)
dir1 files: d1_file1 d1_file2 d1_file3
dir2 has 3 files(s)
dir2 files: d2_file1 d2_file2 d2_file3
```

Basically I would like to build a separate array for each item in the `for loop` that stores values from the `ls` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to only output the count once per directory, you need to move the printing out of the `while read` loop. However, I would suggest removing it entirely. Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

list=(
dir1
dir2
)

for dir in "${list[@]}"; do
    files=( ./tmp/"$dir"/* )
    echo "${dir} has ${#files[@]} files(s)"
    echo "${dir} files: ${files[@]}"
done
```

This uses a glob to populate the `files` array with the contents of each directory.

In general, parsing `ls` should be avoided.

Comment: It looks like `files` variable is empty when I move the print out of the `while loop`?

Comment: @HTF that's because piping creates a sub shell, so variables declared inside are lost. There are ways around this but I would suggest avoiding the problem entirely and using the approach I have suggested in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, please note that this is just a pseudo code, basically I didn't want to paste the whole script so I just used `ls` for example. The original script is used to iterate through AWS S3 buckets.

Comment: @HTF fair enough, in that case one option would be to pipe the other aws command to a block `{ while read; do ... done; echo ... }`

Comment: Thanks, reference is someone else will need this info: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [pathname expansion (globbing)](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) to capture all the files in your subdirectories:

```
list=(
 dir1
 dir2
)

for dir in "${list[@]}"; do
    files=( ./tmp/"${dir}"/* )  # collect all matches in array
    echo "${dir} has ${#files[@]} files(s)"
    echo "${dir} files: ${files[@]}"
done
```

Note how I've double-quoted `${list[@]}` and `${dir}` to protect their values from [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html).
By contrast, the `*` *must* be *unquoted* so as to trigger pathname expansion.

Comment: Exactly. At least our stories check out!

Comment: @TomFenech: :) ++ for providing a better explanation.